# How can I remove my discrete GPU?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu

I am having some software issue with my NVidia GPU and is causing all sorts of problems, and I can't disable it in BIOS.

I looked up the schematic for my motherboard, and here is what I saw:

[image]

Below is a picture of my motherboard:
[image]

I am pretty sure that one of the two gold colored boxes is my GPU, and the other is my CPU.

Which one is which? In general, how can I read the diagram and tell the difference?

Comment: The diagram won't tell you that, its a logical model, and has little relation to the physical layout of the components beyond wiring considerations. Either way, be prepared to put it back in if the system freaks out over the missing component, so don't break it to get it out.

Comment: Why would it freak out about a missing discrete GPU?

Comment: Firmware is very set-in stone, and laptop manufacturers usually keep the configurations to themselves. They also jealously "protect" their products from their users. Besides, perhaps there actually is a good reason they didn't give you a cmos setting for disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Based off the mounting bracket of the heat sinks, I would say the left one is the CPU and the right is the GPU.  If you really want to know, remove the heat sinks and fan and see whats written on each chip.

Unfortunately, its difficult to tell using the diagram you found which is which.  That diagram is more for electrical engineers who would design the circuit board.  It does not directly correlate to how the finished product would look.

To answer whether or not you can remove the GPU, you would have to remove the fan, as well as unscrew all the screws holding down those heat sinks on the GPU and CPU. Even then though, that GPU may be directly soldered to the board (likely is).

Comment: What diagram would be more helpful? Is there any other way to disable to GPU?

Comment: have you contacted the manufacturer? lots of them have chat help nowadays, which is quite convenient.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find a diagram that will help you for what you are looking for - there probably isn't one.  And if you don't have some other form of displaying graphics (such as integrated graphics in your CPU), you won't see an output at all.  Disabling your GPU would leave you without a screen unless that CPU has integrated graphics.